# Counting lowercase using recursion and low and high parameters

Tags: python

So im trying to create a recursive function that can count the amount of lowercase numbers in a word. This is what I have so far and im having difficulty implementing the low and high parameters that determine the range the function is checking.

```
 def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    count = 0
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    elif s[low].islower():
        count+=1
    count_lowercase(s[low+1:high])

    return count
```

Comment: Why use recursion here? Why not just splice the section of a string you want to check?

Comment: For starters, if `s[low].islower()` is true, which character should the function check next? Right, the _next_ character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the recursion step on the return, so they get called for every size until done.

This code does it, `high` defines the position of limit:

```
def count_lowercase(s, high=0):
    count = 0

    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    if high == 0:
        high = len(s)
    if s[0].islower():
        count+=1
    return count + count_lowercase(s[1:high+1])
```

Comment: You don't need the `low` kwarg, since it's always 0 and never specified on subsequent calls

Comment: @C.Nivs True, removed it

Comment: i need a high parameter also, i dont always want to do the entire word

Comment: lol, what happened to the low parameter, I need to be able to count it from any position in the word. This helped a lot though, thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that checks if the first character is lowercase and recursively adds the number of lowercase characters in the rest of the string, or returns 0 if the string is empty:

```
def count_lowercase(s):
    return len(s) and s[0].islower() + count_lowercase(s[1:])
```